# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size' in kivy when it's a exe file

Tags: python, kivy

I'm following Codemy's kivy course and I ran into an error. I used auto_py_to_exe and I added my .kv file. But it says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'. Here's my calc.py file
'''

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

# Set the app size
Window.size = (500, 600)



class MyLayout(Widget):
    def clear(self):
        self.ids.calc_input.text = '0'

    def math_sign(self, sign):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        self.ids.calc_input.text = f"{prior}{sign}"

    def button_press(self, sign):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text

        if "Error" in prior:
            self.ids.calc_input.text = ''

        if prior == "0":
            self.ids.calc_input.text = ""
            self.ids.calc_input.text = str(sign)

        else:
            self.ids.calc_input.text += str(sign)

    def remove(self):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        prior = prior[:-1]
        self.ids.calc_input.text = prior

    def dot(self):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        num_list = prior.split("+")

        if "+" or "*" or "/" in prior and "." not in num_list[-1]:
            self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{prior}.'

        elif "." in prior:
            pass
        else:
            self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{prior}.'

    def pos_neg(self):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        if "-" in prior:
            prior = prior[1:]

        else:
            prior = f"-{prior}"

        self.ids.calc_input.text = prior

    def equals(self):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        try:
            answer = eval(prior)
            self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)

        except:
            self.ids.calc_input.text = "Error"
        
        if "+" in prior:
            num_list = prior.split("+")
            answer = 0.0
            for number in num_list:
                answer = answer + float(number)

            self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
   


class CalculatorApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        # Designate Our .kv design file
        Builder.load_file('calc.kv')
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CalculatorApp().run()
```

'''

and the calc.kv file
'''

```
<MyLayout>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        TextInput:
            id: calc_input
            text:"0"
            halign: "right"
            size_hint: (1,.15)
            font_size: 50

        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            rows: 5

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "%"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "C"
                on_press: root.clear()

            Button:
                id: clear
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: u"\u00AB"
                on_press: root.remove()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "/"
                on_press: root.math_sign("/")

            # Row
            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "7"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(7)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "8"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(8)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "9"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(9)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "x"
                on_press: root.math_sign("*")

            # Row
            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "4"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(4)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "5"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(5)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "6"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(6)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "-"
                on_press: root.math_sign("-")

            # Row
            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "1"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(1)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "2"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(2)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "3"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(3)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "+"
                on_press: root.math_sign("+")

            # Row
            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "+/-"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.pos_neg()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "0"
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(0)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "."
                background_color: (157 / 255, 157 / 255, 157 / 255, 1)
                on_press: root.dot()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "="
                on_press: root.equals()
```

'''
I also tried to his video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEko7jWYKiE&list=PLCC34OHNcOtpz7PJQ7Tv7hqFBP_xDDjqg&index=20) but it said couldn't execute script calc. What can I do?

Comment: This probably means Window hasn't been created, probably there is a problem with your bundled kivy. I don't know what, see if you can get the full logs. It may be an issue with the build tool you used.

Comment: Hello and thank you for responding. How can I get the full logs? I used pyinstaller to build it.